# How can i get x y z coordinates of pointcloud from a point (x,y) of color image D435

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using object detection on color image and i have a point (x,y), it is center bounding box of object.
From this point, I want to get x y z coordinates of this point from pointcloud.
I have used this function to get data:  point_cloud2.read_points(data,field_names=('x', 'y', 'z'),skip_nans=True,uvs=[(x,y)])
But shape of pointcloud data is 160x120 while shape of color image is 640x480.
How can I get more data from pointcloud to shape is 640x480.
Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368880/how-can-i-get-x-y-z-coordinates-of-pointcloud-from-a-point-(x,y)-of-color-image-d435/) by [NhatHuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/66507/nhathuy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @NhatHuy,

Refer to this post, You will find your answer, and at the end of the post click on "Show more comments" You will be able to get Z location from the point cloud.

https://answers.ros.org/question/367829/how-to-obtain-quaternion-from-x

Check this python code for demo:

https://github.com/osrf/baxter_demos/blob/master/scripts/get_goal_poses.py

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arifzaman](https://answers.ros.org/users/69915/arifzaman/) on 2021-05-26**:
Respected Sir,
I am working on Ubunto 20.4 with ROS noetic. I am having intel Real sense D415 camera by which I can visualize the point cloud on Rviz.

```
I want to get xyz coordinates of each pointcloud and from that I want to separate and print min and max point xyz coordinates.
```

I am very much new to ROS and doesn't have good programming experience as well. I will be very much thankful if anyone can share me any sample code or guide me step by step as i have searched almost all ROS forums but didn't get my answer.

I also asked a ques can you plz help me out
https://answers.ros.org/question/379029/how-to-get-xyz-coordinates-of-pointcloud-using-intel-real-sense-d415/